# automatic height for -[tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

**tl, dr:** I really wish I could set **all** the properties of the section header, including its height, in the storyboard. Is there a way I can do that?

There's something I could never get around in the CocoaTouch API.

The `UITableViewDelegate` contains a method called `-[tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]`, which must return the appropriate height for a header in a section.

The best practices I know of advise to separate presentation and logic. Yet, a `UITableViewDelegate` seems to mix these two concepts: it handles the interaction (`didSelect...`) and some aspects of the presentation (`heightForHeader...`).

Furthermore, I often define the section headers in the storyboards, therefore making both the storyboard and the (typically) view controller highly interdependent for the section headers.

Is there a way I could find out the height in a generic way, or just make this method "automatic"? I used to get the section header and return its height, but it's actually a performance issue when there are many section headers.

Answer (score 0):

you should draw an arbitrary header in that `tableView:heightForHeader` method and return the height of that arbitrary header to get dynamic header size. that worked for me. hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally found it this morning :)

1. In the storyboard, select the tableview.
2. On the inspector panel (on the right on Xcode), select the "Measurements" tab.
3. On that tab, chances are that the first section, "tableview" is collapsed. Expand it
4. Set the appropriate section header height

And delete the `-[tableView:heightForSectionHeader:]` \o/